# VBA - Previously functioning code not working on new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This one's a little wordy, so please bear with me...

In this new Excel program, there are several master tables in separate sheets. I'll highlight 2 of the relevant masters:

```
Die Master
----------------------------------------
| Die No | Desc | Preven. Stroke | PIC |
========================================
| D00001 | Test |    1000000     | Me  |
----------------------------------------

Model Master
----------------------
| Model | Model Name | 
======================
| M0001 |   Model 1  |
----------------------
```

Then in a new sheet, `Project Entry` have `Die No` and `Model` columns in the table.

```
Project Registration
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Project No | Machine | Die No | Die Desc | Model | Model Name  |
==================================================================
|   P00001   |   A00   | D00001 |   Test   | M0001 |   Model 1   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`Die Desc` and `Model Name` are filled in automatically using values from `Die No` and `Model` respectively.  Because I don't want the formula to be tampered with, I'm going to place it in VBA code:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

'Autofill Die Description after Die No is filled
If Not Intersect(target, Me.ListObjects("D.Entry").ListColumns("Die No").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

 With target.Offset(0, 1) 'Die Desc
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFerror(INDEX(B.Die,MATCH(rc[-1],B.Die[Die No],0),2),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
 End With

End If

'Autofill Model Name after Model is filled
If Not Intersect(target, Me.ListObjects("D.Entry").ListColumns("Model").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

 With target.Offset(0, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFerror(INDEX(C.Model,MATCH(rc[-1],C.Model[Model],0),2),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
 End With
End If
```

The code works and I can proceed with the next sheet, `Data Entry` where  I plan to use the same code as in `Project Entry, using it as the reference table this time.

```
Data Entry
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Project No | Machine | Die No | Die Desc | Model | Model Name |
=================================================================
|   P00001   |         |        |          |       |            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Starting off with `Machine` column, I used the code similar to earlier like so:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change1(ByVal target1 As Range)

'If Project No is not empty then do the following
If Not Intersect(target1, Me.ListObjects("F.Main").ListColumns("Project No").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

 With target1.Offset(0, 1) 
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFerror(INDEX(D.Entry,MATCH(rc[-1],D.Entry[Machine],0),2),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
 End With
End If
```

However, when testing it nothing appears for machine column. Even changing the `rc` value changes nothing. How can a similar code can work on one sheet and suddenly cannot work on the next?

Comment: `worksheet_change1` There is no event with that name. You can have only one `Worksheet.Change` event in a sheet and it has to be placed in the sheet code area. Also it is written as `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)` You cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `worksheet_change1` is something you created? I'm pretty sure that's not reserved [sheet event name](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/workbook-worksheet-events-excel-vba), which means it probably never runs your macro. You need to move your code into the appropriate sheet `Data Entry` with the same name of `Worksheet_Change`

If you're still having issues, the below code might help you debug it. Step through your code and you'll figure it out:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

MsgBox "Your macro is running where it's supposed to."
Stop


'If Project No is not empty then do the following
    If Not Intersect(target1, Me.ListObjects("F.Main").ListColumns("Project No").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

    With target1.Offset(0, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFerror(INDEX(D.Entry,MATCH(rc[-1],D.Entry[Machine],0),2),"""")"
    .Value = .Value
    End With

    Else
        MsgBox "Couldn't find what you were looking for"

    End If
End Sub
```